# Free memory that sent to background child process as argument

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system

I have an exercise - to implement simple shell.
Since I have to implement the background operator ('&'), I can't send the arguments when they are on the buffer (because the new process maybe continue running after the next command and the buffer is overwritten). I allocate memory for each arg list, and because of the process is background and I don't wait for him, I don't know when to free the memory.

How I should do it?

Demonstrating (without buffer):

```
int main(){
  char **toSend = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3 );
  toSend[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
  strcpy(toSend[0], "ls");
  toSend[1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
  strcpy(toSend[1], "-a");
  toSend[2] = NULL;
  if( !fork() ){
    int devNull = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
    dup2(devNull, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(devNull);
    execvp(toSend[0], toSend);
  }
  free(toSend[0]); //???
  free(toSend[1]); //???
  free(toSend);    //???
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

By the way, I will be happy to know if the using of the devNull pointer for create background process is correct.

Thanks in advance! and sorry for my bad English...

Comment: You should probably have code to print an error message and exit with a failure status (e.g. `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`) after the `execvp()`.  The `exec*()` family of system calls only return if the call fails; you don't need to check the return value.  But you do want to avoid reporting success on failure, which your code would currently do.  And in more complex shells, you don't want to end up with two processes trying to read data from the terminal; that way lies insanity.

Comment: Also, why do you not want to see the output from your `ls` command?  It would often be good to supply `/dev/null` as the standard input for a command (if it isn't coming from a pipe, for example).  Obviously, sometimes you want to lose the output, but it isn't obvious that's a good idea in this case.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's only example. If the user wrote "appname &" then I should run it on background, and not redirect output to my stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct.

In the child process, after `execvp()`, its memory image is replaced by a new program, so you do not need to call `free()` in it. But you still need to call `free()` in the parent process, as you did in your example code.

Actually, because parent and child are different processes, you could define `toSend` as local buffer, instead of allocate memory for it dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. According to it, I can use the buffer for send args?
(And continue use the buffer for the next line?)

Comment: @zardav Yes, they are in different processes.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the using of the devNull for create background process is correct?

Comment: @zardav If you want to ignore the output of your backgroup program, then it is correct. Otherwise, it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

free(toSend) will just free the address with it.First you free(toSend[0]) which frees all the address allocated using the first address till it encounters address which was not allocated by toSend pointer.